# how to use angular resource sails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sails.js

i am using angular resource sails.

```
var items = sailsResource('roles').query(); // GET /item
$scope.roles = items;
angular.forEach($scope.roles, function(value, key) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

output: undefined.

How to parse this query?

Comment: is there something in `items` variable after the `query()` call?

Comment: @ronen.. it is working ng-repeat  but it is not working forloop or  angular,foreach..   console.log(items.length); not working

Comment: https://github.com/angular-resource-sails/angular-resource-sails. this document i am following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` method is asynchronous. `sailsResource` creates [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) API compatible services so you have to do your looping in a callback function.

For example

```
$scope.roles = sailsResource('roles').query(function(roles) {
    angular.forEach(roles, function(value, key) {
        // and so on
    });
});
```

---

You can also use the `$promise` property to access the promise, eg

```
$scope.roles = sailsResource('roles').query();

$scope.roles.$promise.then(function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.roles, function(value, key) {
        // etc
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. i have used this

Answer (score 2):

Check this part of the documentation: https://github.com/angular-resource-sails/angular-resource-sails#success-and-error-callbacks

If you want to access the data you fetched, you'll probably have to provide the query function with callbacks. So your code would become

```
sailsResource('roles').query(function(items) { // GET /item
    $scope.roles = items;
    angular.forEach($scope.roles, function(value, key) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    });
});
```